# Python: Reverse Function Works Sometimes

Tags: python

I'm using codeacademy to learn Python and got to this:

> Define a function called reverse that takes a string textand returns
>   that string in reverse.

I have the following:

```
def reverse(text):
    l = len(text)-1
    for t in text:
        print text[l]
        l-=1
```

On CA it doesn't work but on http://pythonfiddle.com/python-noob-scratchpad/ and https://repl.it/languages/python it does

I get the error `Oops, try again. Your function fails on reverse("Python!"). It returns "None" when it should return "!nohtyP".`

I realise there are other ways to do it but why is this way wrong? I noticed changing https://repl.it/languages/python from v3 to 'normal' made it work so is CA using v3?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. It just prints letters. They probably want you to return the reversed string.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is. It should return the string, not just print it.

Comment: With `print text[l]` you are printing out the letters, not returning them from the function.

Comment: So embarrassed right now... can't see the wood through the trees. Also thanks to those down voting the question. Say classy!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for code academy to accept your code, you have to return the reversed function, not just print it. Your code might look something like this (notice the difference):

```python
def reverse(text):
    returnValue = ""
    l = len(text)-1
    for t in text:
        returnValue = returnValue + text[l]
        l-=1
    return returnValue
```

then,

```
print reverse("Python!")
```

will print:

```
!nohtyP
```